# how to select partial data from a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe,
flag=np.sign(value)

```
ticker    value    flag    cumsum(flag)
A1        -1.5     -1         -1
B1         1.4      1         0       
C3        -2.4     -1         -1 
D4        -1.8     -1         -2
E6        -1.6     -1         -3
```

I have a variable, cutoff = 1 (it is always +ve, its a modulus)

how can I best select the tickers where abs(cumsum(flag)) <= 1

i.e., expected output is [A1, B1, C3]

i.e I want to keep going down the cumsum list until I find the LAST 1 or -1

I tried a loop:

```
ticker_list_keep = []
for y in range(0, len(df['cumsum']), 1):
if abs(df['cumsum'][y]) < abs(capacity) + 1: 
ticker_list_keep.append(df.index[y])
```

but this would give me only A1 and C3, and would miss out B2

Thanks

per note on comments:
@Vaishali - The question is not a duplicate. I wanted ALL the values in the ticker list, up until we get to the final -1 in the cumsum list.

Above, we get to the final abs(val)=1 at C3, so my list is C3, B1,A1.

Your solution the thread you pointed me to gives only A1 and C3.

You notice A1 is not the final -1 in the cumsum list, therefore A1 alone doesn't suffice. We note C3 is where the final +/-1 occurs therefore our required list is A1,B1,C3

Thanks!!

Comment: Try df[df['cumsum(flag)'].abs() <= 1]

Comment: @ Vaishali - Hi, that doesn't work. That given me the SAME output as what my loop gave. It does not give the expected output of A1, B1, C3 (it missed out B2)... any ideas?

Comment: @Vaishali - The question is not a duplicate. I wanted ALL the values in the ticker list, up until we get to the final -1 in the cumsum list. Above, we get to the final abs(val)=1 at C3, so my list is C3, B1,A1.    You notice A1 is not the final -1 in the cumsum list, therefore A1 alone doesn't suffice.

Comment: Your sample df does not have ticker B2 so difficult to understand the desired behavior. You can try the answer I just posted and let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find last valid index based on your condition and create a slice.

```
idx = df[df['cumsum(flag)'].abs() <= 1].last_valid_index()
df.loc[:idx, :]

    ticker  value   flag    cumsum(flag)
0   A1      -1.5    -1      -1
1   B1       1.4     1       0
2   C3      -2.4    -1      -1
```